# SAP JCO Function Modules for CCMS

Tags: abap, jco, bapi, sap-basis

I am currently writing a small application to fetch CCMS data (RZ20), i am unable to get the monitoring details using BAPI for data like ENQUEUE, JAVA, ABAP etc...

Is there some document or someplace where i can find this data? or can help me get the Functional Module names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a set of BAPIs to read monitor values. You have to logon to the XM interface first. I haven't used those BAPIs myself yet, so I can not speak from experience. There is a SAP document (PDF) describing the BAPIs available: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/da47d190-0201-0010-ac9a-e236663563e0?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&5003637377319